# Random Forest--prioritizing response variables

Tags: r, random-forest, feature-selection, weights

Is there a way to prioritize response variables in a random forest model, ideally in R?
For example, suppose I want to predict tree height based on elevation, aspect, slope, and tree canopy cover. In theory, if I have areas of no vegetation, and I only use elevation, aspect, and slope, so no variable that would signify the presence of trees, I can still predict a tree height. And if I add tree canopy cover to my model, where larger values of tree cover would mean greater tree heights, then I might still have areas of no trees where the model predicts a tree height. So is there a way to make the variable tree canopy cover more important in the random forest model? Ideally, I would like for areas where canopy cover = 0 the model to predict tree height = 0. And the higher the canopy cover, the higher the tree height. I could just use the variable canopy cover to predict canopy height but I know that all the other variables also play a role in the tree height.

I found information on applying weights to a random forest model, but in those cases the weight is applied to the predicted variable. For example if tree height was a categorical variable of three classes, by using weights, I could tell the model how many observations to use from each class. But I would like to apply weights on my response variables.

There are two other resources that refer to case.weights() but I am still not sure how to proceed.

[Handling case weight in the Random Forest packages in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/166424/handling-case-weight-in-the-random-forest-packages-in-r)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75150837/assigning-weights-to-variables-in-random-forest-model-in-r

I am mainly using randomForest and ranger packages in R but I am open to other packages, too.

Comment: I'm a little confused at this question. Are you talking about a model with multiple outputs/responses? Or about prioritizing one specific input/feature? Or ensuring that specific outputs/responses are learned for specific inputs/features?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I am talking about prioritizing one variable. For example, I would like the variable canopy cover to have a bigger contribution to the model than elevation, aspect, or slope. Ideally, if canopy cover =0 tree height should be 0. The model would still be "canopy height ~ canopy cover + elevation +aspect + slope". But canopy cover would have weights or some other way of making it more important in the model. Maybe it's not possible with these types of models? I appreciate any guidance.