# RandomForest and class weights

Tags: r, random-forest

Question in one sentence: **Does somebody know how to determine good class weights for a random forest?**

Explanation:
I am playing around with imbalanced datasets. I want to use the `R` package `randomForest` in order to train a model on a very skewed dataset with only little positive examples and many negative examples. I know, there are other methods and in the end I will make use of them but for technical reasons, building a random forest is an intermediate step. So I played around with the parameter `classwt`. I am setting up a very artificial dataset of 5000 negative examples in the disc with radius 2 and then I sample 100 positives examples in the disc with radius 1. What I suspect is that

**1) without class weighting the model becomes 'degenerate', i.e. predicts `FALSE` everywhere.**

**2) with a fair class weighting I will see a 'green dot' in the middle, i.e. it will predict the disc with radius 1 as `TRUE` although there are negative examples.**

This is how the data looks like:

[image]

This is what happens without weighting: (call is: `randomForest(x = train[, .(x,y)],y = as.factor(train$z),ntree = 50)`)

[image]

For checking I have also tried what happens when I violently balance the dataset by downsampling the negative class so that the relationship is 1:1 again. This gives me the expected result:

[image]

However, when I compute a model with a class weighting of 'FALSE' = 1, 'TRUE' = 50 (this is a fair weighting as there are 50 times more negatives than positives) then I get this:

[image]

Only when I set the weights to some weird value like 'FALSE' = 0.05 and 'TRUE' = 500000 then I get senseful results:

[image]

And this is quite unstable, i.e. changing the 'FALSE' weight to 0.01 makes the model degenerate again (i.e. it predicts `TRUE` everywhere).

**Question: Does somebody know how to determine good class weights for a random forest?**

R code:

```
library(plot3D)
library(data.table)
library(randomForest)
set.seed(1234)
amountPos = 100
amountNeg = 5000

# positives
r = runif(amountPos, 0, 1)
phi = runif(amountPos, 0, 2*pi)
x = r*cos(phi)
y = r*sin(phi)
z = rep(T, length(x))
pos = data.table(x = x, y = y, z = z)

# negatives
r = runif(amountNeg, 0, 2)
phi = runif(amountNeg, 0, 2*pi)
x = r*cos(phi)
y = r*sin(phi)
z = rep(F, length(x))
neg = data.table(x = x, y = y, z = z)

train = rbind(pos, neg)

# draw train set, verify that everything looks ok
plot(train[z == F]$x, train[z == F]$y, col="red")
points(train[z == T]$x, train[z == T]$y, col="green")
# looks ok to me :-)

Color.interpolateColor = function(fromColor, toColor, amountColors = 50) {
  from_rgb = col2rgb(fromColor)
  to_rgb = col2rgb(toColor)

  from_r = from_rgb[1,1]
  from_g = from_rgb[2,1]
  from_b = from_rgb[3,1]

  to_r = to_rgb[1,1]
  to_g = to_rgb[2,1]
  to_b = to_rgb[3,1]

  r = seq(from_r, to_r, length.out = amountColors)
  g = seq(from_g, to_g, length.out = amountColors)
  b = seq(from_b, to_b, length.out = amountColors)

  return(rgb(r, g, b, maxColorValue = 255))
}
DataTable.crossJoin = function(X,Y) {
  stopifnot(is.data.table(X),is.data.table(Y))
  k = NULL
  X = X[, c(k=1, .SD)]
  setkey(X, k)
  Y = Y[, c(k=1, .SD)]
  setkey(Y, k)
  res = Y[X, allow.cartesian=TRUE][, k := NULL]
  X = X[, k := NULL]
  Y = Y[, k := NULL]
  return(res)
}

drawPredictionAreaSimple = function(model) {
  widthOfSquares = 0.1
  from = -2
  to = 2

  xTable = data.table(x = seq(from=from+widthOfSquares/2,to=to-widthOfSquares/2,by = widthOfSquares))
  yTable = data.table(y = seq(from=from+widthOfSquares/2,to=to-widthOfSquares/2,by = widthOfSquares))
  predictionTable = DataTable.crossJoin(xTable, yTable)
  pred = predict(model, predictionTable)
  res = rep(NA, length(pred))
  res[pred == "FALSE"] = 0
  res[pred == "TRUE"] = 1
  pred = res
  predictionTable = predictionTable[, PREDICTION := pred]
  #predictionTable = predictionTable[y == -1 & x == -1, PREDICTION := 0.99]
  col = Color.interpolateColor("red", "green")

  input = matrix(c(predictionTable$x, predictionTable$y), nrow = 2, byrow = T)
  m = daply(predictionTable, .(x, y), function(x) x$PREDICTION)
  image2D(z = m, x = sort(unique(predictionTable$x)), y = sort(unique(predictionTable$y)), col = col, zlim = c(0,1))
}


rfModel = randomForest(x = train[, .(x,y)],y = as.factor(train$z),ntree = 50)
rfModelBalanced = randomForest(x = train[, .(x,y)],y = as.factor(train$z),ntree = 50, classwt = c("FALSE" = 1, "TRUE" = 50))
rfModelBalancedWeird = randomForest(x = train[, .(x,y)],y = as.factor(train$z),ntree = 50, classwt = c("FALSE" = 0.05, "TRUE" = 500000))


drawPredictionAreaSimple(rfModel)
title("unbalanced")
drawPredictionAreaSimple(rfModelBalanced)
title("balanced with weights")
pos = train[z == T]
neg = train[z == F]
neg = neg[sample.int(neg[, .N], size = 100, replace = FALSE)]
trainSampled = rbind(pos, neg)
rfModelBalancedSampling = randomForest(x = trainSampled[, .(x,y)],y = as.factor(trainSampled$z),ntree = 50)
drawPredictionAreaSimple(rfModelBalancedSampling)
title("balanced with sampling")


drawPredictionAreaSimple(rfModelBalancedWeird)
title("balanced with weird weights")
```

Comment: if sampsize works why not use that? I also found sampsize works better to resolve this, as did others. Also see a great answer here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157714/r-package-for-weighted-random-forest-classwt-option

Comment: daply is in plyr, you should call that.

Comment: classwt Priors of the classes. Need not add up to one. Ignored for regression.

Comment: @Diego: This parameter seems to be very problematic, I do not understand how this parameter behaves (see the comments in the question!)...

Answer (score 4):

Don't use a hard cutoff to classify a hard membership, and don't use KPIs that depend on such a hard membership prediction. Instead, work with a probabilistic prediction, using `predict(..., type="prob")`, and assess these using proper [scoring-rules](/questions/tagged/scoring-rules).

This earlier thread should be helpful: [Why is accuracy not the best measure for assessing classification models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352) Unsurprisingly enough, I believe [my answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/312787/1352) would be particularly helpful (sorry for the shamelessness), as would [an earlier answer of mine](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/312124/1352).

Comment: this is the topic you spoke about today, right? I will look out for this in my work :-)